# Styling Cordova's In-App Browser Window Chrome

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I was wondering if it was possible to inject `css` that styles the (`html`?) elements of the chrome around the in-app browser windows.

I've found [insertCSS](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#insertcss) in the documentations but I'm unclear whether it's for styling the chrome of the browser window or the content inside of the window?

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.insertCSS({file: "mystyles.css"});
});
```

If it is possible to style the in-app browser chrome, where can I find all the elements and selectors (classes or ids) used?

Comment: You can customize your innappbrowser icons that are in your plugin directory.  That is your only control.  (After packaged up with phonegap, rename the .app file to .zip and open, you will have a directory called "innappbrowser" and inside are your files)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. After the changes are made, change the file extension back from `.zip` to `.app`? Did the results work as expected when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forked InAppBrowser and created plugin that allows you to style the browser extensively. But I've only done it for iOS and Android. Please take a look
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Answer (score 2):

As Joerg said, insertCSS is just to add some css to the page you display inside the `inAppBrowser` plugin, I use it to hide some things like toolbars, headers and other elements I don't want to show.

To edit the inAppBrowser plugin itself, you can download the plugin from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (or create a fork on github), change the icons and then install the plugin using the local path (or your github fork url) instead of installing it using the plugin id.

```
cordova plugin add /path/to/your/plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

The insertCSS is for styling the HTML file. There is no way to style the inappbrowser itself.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I need to explore Adam's suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205655/styling-cordovas-in-app-browser-window-chrome#comment44779980_28205655. Changing icons will have good but minor effect on the overall style. Have you any experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience to modify the inAppBrowser. But I think you have to rewrite the plugin or you have to write your own.